# In stabilizer codes, I am not getting why do we need logical operators X-bar and Z-bar

Tags: stabilizer-code

[image]

In the image below for stabilizers for shors 9 qubit QECC, I understand the role of S1 to S8 operators but I am not getting role of X-bar and Z-bar operators. I know how to obtain them using standard form but not clear with its use and why do we need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use $S_1$ to $S_8$ on 9 qubits, you are left with a space of dimension 2. When you see something of dimension 2, you think "aha! an effective qubit". But to properly describe a qubit, you need two anti-commuting operators, conventionally $X$ and $Z$. Think: two axes of the Bloch sphere.

So, the $\bar X$ and $\bar Z$ are the operators that anti-commute with each other, giving the algebra of qubit, while operating entirely within the two-dimensional subspace (i.e. commuting with $S_1$ to $S_8$).

Comment: thanks for this explanation. I interpret this as, as we have X and Z operators acting on single qubit 0 and 1 state, we have X-bar and Z-bar operators acting on 9 qubits logical 0 and logical 1 states.

Comment: yes, exactly that.